# Any performance benefits of large inode sizes (ext4)

Tags: samba, ext4, inode

We have a video editing server split into two partitions. One for video footage and one for projects. On the projects partition there is totally 7TB of data and 250,000 files. Of these, 50,000 of them are < 1600 bytes in size. I would like to know if we would get any performance benefits from increasing the inode size from the default 256 bytes, to 2048 bytes. Would the file system automatically store these 1600 byte files inline with the inode metadata?

We mount the shares to Windows and Mac clients using samba. I have noticed that when moving a directory containing 10000s of small files, between folders on the same share (using a Windows client), the move operation takes 3-4 minutes to complete, even though no data is being transferred anywhere. So I'm guessing just the file pointer updates must be taking this long. Would having 20% of the files stored inline with their inodes improve this?

From my calculations, it seems like it would cost us about 300 MB in extra space (which is negligable). So is there any reason not to try this?

Note: the file system is currently formatted with a block size of 4K, and the underlying NVMe SSD disk has a block size of 4K (which can be reformatted to 512B)

Comment: a move of a directory containing many files taking long is no surprise – the windows client is probably just getting a list of all files, attributes… just to move them.

Comment: But if anything, storing data in the inodes will make such a transfer slower, not faster, because now when changing the location of things, you suddenly *do* have to touch the data.

Comment: On Linux the directory rename *shouldn't* take longer regardless of how many files are in the folder.  That must be a windows thing?  The only reason this might be modifying the files is if you are using project quotas, and moving the folder between projects?